# Progress bar doesn't show up and UI thread seems to hang up

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I am setting a ProgressBar VISIBLE before calling the following function. The problem is progress bar doesn't show up at all. Also, if the call takes too long, my ui seems to freeze.

```
private var enrolledEventsList: List<EnrolledEventModel>? = null
fun getEnrolledEvents(userEmail: String): List<EnrolledEventModel> {

        enrolledEventsList = CbreCommunityRetrofit
                .getRetrofit()
                .getEnrolledEvents(userEmail)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .onErrorReturn { enrolledEventsList ?: listOf() }
                .blockingFirst()

        return enrolledEventsList ?: listOf()
    }
```

Comment: Hey, you should definitely provide more code. It's impossible to help you at the moment.

Comment: post enough code here

Comment: There's something wrong with the architecture of your application. The very first issue is that you're blocking the UI thread. I recommend you read some guides or look at open source software that also use Rx and Retrofit. Please refrain from guessing how you think the code works.

Comment: @JanRadzikowski Posted code is enough to check. `blockingFirst` is the culprit because it will ignore the threads, will do the operation on UI thread.

Comment: Good point! Thanks for that

Answer (score 4):

Your ui is hanging because you're blocking the main thread with the `blockingFirst()` call but the observable can't notify another element because you specified with `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` that the notification has to be done on the same (blocked) thread.
In my opinion, when using Rx, avoid `blockingFirst()` because it's a common source of deadlocks

Answer (score 0):

If you have high resolution pics in your app, please reduce its resolution. And you use Retrofit on mainThread, try without that code.